# Spring Boot OAuth, getting Null Pointer Exception in JwtTokenStore class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implementing OAuth2 into a Spring Boot API for the first time.

I've managed to get a access token from the API, but when I try to use it to make a call to the API I'm getting the following error;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.convertAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:92) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:84) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:229) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a1f25c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad6a1bf8.loadAuthentication(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a1f25c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd6c66fe.loadAuthentication(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

This is the request I'm making to the API;

```
GET /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8090
Authorization: Bearer MYTOKENHERE
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This is the class that configures the OAuthServer;

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "myapi";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter));
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter);

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient("12345")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("54321")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(2592000) // 30 days
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3888000); // 15 days more than access token
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

}
```

I've placed a breakpoint on the line where the error is being generated, and it looks to me like the TokenEnhancer is null, which I guess is what it causing the issue, but I don't understand why it's null? Looking at the docs the TokenEnhancer is simply a TokenConverter, which I'm defining as a Bean in this class;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountAuthenticationProvider accountAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(accountAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(env.getProperty("jwt.secret"));
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this one out. I needed to setup the token store to a JdbcTokenStore() and now it works fine. Below is the database structure I've used in my database for the oauth side of things;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_access_token`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_access_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` mediumblob,
  `authentication_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentication` mediumblob,
  `refresh_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`authentication_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_approvals`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_approvals` (
  `userId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clientId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scope` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiresAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastModifiedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_client_details`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_client_details` (
  `client_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `resource_ids` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_secret` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scope` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorized_grant_types` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `web_server_redirect_uri` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorities` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access_token_validity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refresh_token_validity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_information` varchar(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `autoapprove` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_client_token`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_client_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` mediumblob,
  `authentication_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`authentication_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_code`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_code` (
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentication` mediumblob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_refresh_token`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_refresh_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` mediumblob,
  `authentication` mediumblob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then where in my code I was referencing the TokenStore, for example;

```
private TokenStore tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
```

and

```
@Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter));
        }
```

I created a TokenStore bean;

```
@Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
```

Then use that as the token store instead;

```
@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;
```

and

```
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }
```